# How to convert terminal command output (in float) to integer in linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, format

Lets say a command in terminal outputs a value 2.32. I want to convert this output to integer and then display 2 instead of 2.32 in terminal.

Comment: In what shell? Bash?

Comment: @tukan yes in bash

Comment: You have then already high quality answers - for example - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89712/how-to-convert-floating-point-number-to-integer

Comment: printf is not working in my case @tukan

Comment: Why it is not working?  What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
$ echo "2.32" | sed 's/.[0-9]*$//'
2
```